# IOS app : Measure between 2 points in a picture taken

Tags: ios

I made an application, not very complicated, that can take a picture from the iphone.

I would like to know if this is possible:  User positions points within a picture (manually), and a common scaled object inform for the purposes of calculation, and so with the  points and the size of our known object (the scale) calculate the surface cover by the points the user has chosen. The best would be that the app detect automatically the scale.

I haven't find so much things on internet about that.

Thanks for your reply, i can post you the code i made, but it is not very complicated, it is just an app that can take picture .
Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. It's sometimes known as "rotoscoping", but this term got swiped by animators for something different. However it will not be entirely automatic, the user will have to make an accommodation (guess) of the difference in perspective and depth, and its impact on scale, from one object (that which determines corresponding scale) and the object being measured.

The process is aligning common perspective, or forcing/creating a common perspective so things can be moved in sync with regards to the camera's view of the scene, and then compared and/or moved accordingly.

This same approach would gain you the ability (with a common object for scale) to contrast the size of (and distance between) objects in different scenes/photos.

Here's an interesting paper on how to find and match perspectives, but actually about something similar: http://liris.cnrs.fr/Documents/Liris-3774.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't really need perspective, i will always take the picture from above, it's just a mathematicall app , for like a drawing and i'll put a cube next to the drawing and calculate the surface of the drawing.

So it's much easier than perspective on the link you gave me The surface will always be in 2d, i don't need the 3D in the app But i really don't know how to code that on xcode, so if you have any leads ont the code, or just a bit of code to be complete, that would be awsome

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have a basic grounding on programming in Objective-C or Swift then you won't be able to adapt somebody else's code to your needs. What you want is unique to your needs, so you won't find a perfect fit from somebody else's code. Taking an image, having the user draw lines or a rectangle and using ratios to estimate surface area is pretty simple. Take a look at UIPanGestureRecognizer as a start.

Comment: I've got a basic grounding on objective-c. But the UIPanGestureRecognizer is not much help for me; i just want find the command to put some points on my picture and the link between these points to add some maths formulas inside.

Comment: What I want to do, basically is an app like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcgTWOmOGmc but with a picture instead of the map and a object know for the scale

Comment: A grounding in Objective-C is not the same as a grounding in the frameworks of iOS. Unfortunately the frameworks are somewhere around 50x the size of the Objective-C language, and riddled with weird relationships and oddities. Maybe there is what you ask for, but only someone that has done something similar would know because the APIs and Frameworks are so immense.